# Glitch in the review queue?

Tags: bug, review

While revisiting my review votes I found:

[image: screenshot annotated]

([review](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/243102))

To me this looks like a glitch - either the review is completed or not - the message at the top says *no*, the bottom line says *yes*.

Is my impression wrong?

Comment: It says it is no longer reviewable now. I bet it just got a little confused because of all the leave opens.

Comment: Sounds not improbable :-)